# Create a dynamic list that is updates correctly with the streambuilder in my widget

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I am getting information list from another datasnapshot and after that I assigned it to my itemtile.

The problem is that its only updating once.

When I open it again, it contains the old data and not the new data.

```
List<String> information5 = [];
    
void updateInformation5(List information5) {
    // updated by another snapshot data
    setState(() => information5 = information5);
}

Widget itemList() {
    
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: sample,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    try {
                        return itemTile (
                            itemName: information5[index],
                            itemId: snapshot.data.documents[index].data()["itemId"],
                            imageUrl:information4[index],
                        );
                    } on Exception catch (exception) {
                    
                    } catch (error) {
                    
                    }
                }
            ) : Container(
            
            );
    
        },
    
    );
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `sample`?

Comment: Firestore.instance
        .collection("itemRoom")
        .where('users', arrayContains: itIsMyName)
        .snapshots();